# What's the name for this type of diagram?

Tags: diagram, visio

Today I got a diagram similar to [this one](http://www.databasejournal.com/img/sc_CASETools2_image005.jpg). The diagram I got was produced using Visio which I don't have. I haven't seen such a diagram before and its symbols are not clear to me.

I tried to google it and find some explanations about this specific type of diagram, but to no avail.

Could you please tell me what type of diagram it is, and give me some links to sites about it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like a Unified Modeling Language (UML) diagram, in particular, an [Entity Relationship](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-relationship_model) diagram

Answer (score 2):

Looks like Entity relationship diagram
Entity-relationship modeling is a database modeling method, used to produce a type of conceptual schema, often a relational database, and its requirements in a top-down fashion. Diagrams created by this process are called entity-relationship diagrams.

Answer (score 0):

This is a cardinality diagram, and the lines represent one-to-many relationships.

http://www.smartdraw.com/resources/tutorials/cardinality-notations/

Answer (score 0):

it is an ER diagram and google provides enough links

Answer (score 0):

[Entity-Relationship Diagram](http://databases.about.com/cs/specificproducts/g/er.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone. Using your answers and hints, I finally found out that this specific notation system of ER diagrams is called [Barker Notation](http://www.essentialstrategies.com/publications/modeling/barker.htm) -- that's the answer to my own question :-)

Answer (score -2):

Yes it is entity relationship diagram. As you have mentioned you don’t have Visio, you can download [FREE Visio trial](http://visiotoolbox.com/2010/trial-downloads.aspx) for 60 day. I use Visio to create IT diagrams as it has many great features.